# How to navigate to the next/previous python class?

Tags: python, navigation

I would like to navigate quickly between classes in Python code.
I'm looking for a command to go to the next / previous class so I
can bind that to a key sequence.  This question is not about
graphical navigation tools like treemacs.

It might be interesting to hear about things like hydras too, but
that's also not the focus of this question.

Answer (score 4):

What I found so far and use to navigate between classes in `python-mode`:

First `C-M-u` which runs the command `python-nav-backward-up-list` to navigate up to class definition. After that `C-M-a` (`beginning-of-defun`) and `C-M-e` (`end-of-defun`) to navigate to previous and next class definition respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @muffinmad's answer:

```
(defun my/python-navigate-up-to-class-statement ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((pos nil))
    (while (not (equal pos (point)))
      (setf pos (point))
      (python-nav-backward-up-list))))

(defun my/python-navigate-to-next-python-class ()
  (interactive)
  (my/python-navigate-up-to-class-statement)
  (end-of-defun)
  (end-of-defun)
  (my/python-navigate-up-to-class-statement))

(defun my/python-navigate-to-previous-python-class ()
  (interactive)
  (my/python-navigate-up-to-class-statement)
  (beginning-of-defun))
```

Answer (score 1):

With [Elpy](https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/editing.html#moving-by-indentation)

`C-<up>` and `C-<down>` jump from class to class. Or more accurately: "These commands are used to navigate between lines with same indentation as the current line." Use `C-a` or `Home` first, if you're currently on an indented line.

Note: `M-a` and `M-e` jump from block to block.

---

`C-c C-o`
"Search the buffer for a list of definitions of classes and functions."

Comment: Thanks.  If you know the commands that are bound to those keys for you (e.g. `C-h k C-<up> RET`) that often helps people who use a different config (e.g. doom, spacemacs)